# Better way to notify websocket server from Django

Tags: python, django, websocket, amqp

I have a web application running Django and a separate websocket server. Both using single Django model. When Django make changes to the model, I want Django to notify websocket server about this changes.

Obviously, the way of simply connecting to websocket server and sending one message is looking bad due to increasing server load through connecting/disconnecting clients for each user form submit and due to websocket concept in general.

I've heard about solutions using AMQP server for similar purposes. The question is: is that a good idea, or there are better solutions in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis

Documentation: http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/